# wp_get_attachment_image_src problem

Tags: images

I'm have a problem with the wp_get_attachment_image_src function returning the incorrect url for an image.

My code looks like this:

`$image_main_ar = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_ID, 'product_image_main' );`

product_image_main is a registered image size:

`add_image_size( 'product_image_main', 334, 385, false );`

but when I print the $image_main_ar array I get:

`Array (
[0] => http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Screen-shot-2011-07-27-at-15.03.07.png
[1] => 334
[2] => 226
[3] => )`

which shows the url for the original image I uploaded, not the resized version, and I've checked the resized version is in the upload folder, and the dimension in the array are correct for the resized version.

The weird thing is the fourth key in the array [3] is empty, but on the images where it returns the correct url it is set to '1'. I've looked in the docs but can't find anything about this fourth value.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: if you set add_image size after images where uploaded, it doesn't resize images automatically, try with new image

Comment: Does `wp_get_attachment_image_src` work with other, built in sizes?  Are you called `add_image_size` on its own?  Or hooked into something like `after_setup_theme`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin, that will run through all your media and regenerate thumbnails according to the registered image sizes. Also note that that you're getting the hight parameter as 226 because during add_image_size your third parameter said to not crop the image. Change that to true if you need cropping.

Comment: Yep I've used a regenerator plugin, and checked that the resized version is in the folder, you'd think that if it was able to return the dimensions of the resized image it would return the url of the resized image!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can see there is thread about it here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-regenerate-thumbnails-broken-badly

This has to do with the fact that the attachment meta is not updated correctly. Basically if you look at your database (post meta) you will find that medium and large and thumnail sizes are explicitly defined, but the custom sizes are missing.

Not sure if you the newest wordpress + the newest regenerate thumbnails hard fixed the issue yet though.

Comment: Comment it if its not a answer